# Do older timelines erase or stay parallelly?

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash

I want to know if timelines erase. Let’s put as an example when Barry creates Flashpoint after kissing Iris, did the timeline with Iris disappear, or did he create Flashpoint but the other remained without him, leaving his family alone. If timelines don't disappear, then the Barry we know will never go back in time to see his mother die because that would be him from the other timeline, the original.

I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They seem to erase but then there's the fact that there's a version of Thawne who still exists "after" his history was erased.  So as with my first attempt at an answer, the answer is still "narrative convenience".

Comment: I think the OP is asking what the canon in-universe explanation is, a list of potential ways an author can go isn't very helpful, we all know them anyway.

Comment: But...that actually is the answer for that particular setting.  There is no consistent rule in comics.

Comment: But...that's not the answer you had when I commented, you edited it post comment, it is better now though.

Comment: I dont know because in season one, when Barry goes back in time to try and save his mum, if the timeline is erased, Eobard Thawne wouldn’t have a future going to the future eith his time machine, unleast he goes to the future of Flashpoint.